# Wishart conditionned by the determinant

Tags: conditioning, wishart-distribution, determinant

I am interested in the density of the Wishart distribution under the constraint that the determinant of the outcome is 1.

It suffice do divide the density of the Wishart by the marginal density of the determinant, however, I don't see how to compute this marginal density.

Does it have an explicite expression (maybe in small dimension) ? Or are there techniques to numerically estimate it ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is answered here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268149/determinant-of-real-wishart-matrix#:~:text=The%20Distribution%20of%20the%20Determinant,2P%E2%88%92N%2B1.